# How to model the top of helmet?

Tags: modeling

[image]

How can I model this?I have it modeled from the front view, but how can I make it match the right view? What ever I do on the right view messes up the front view. How can I do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Being in view from the right, move adjacent vertices (and position them according to reference) with X asix blocked (in your case). It's a good idea to turn on proportional editing doing that, so to not grab vertices one by one rather than all together

Answer (score 2):

you can make your life easier with a mirror modifier and deleting 1 half of your mesh.
In side view (<kbd>3</kbd>), select the bottom loop (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right click on an edge), activate proportionnal editing with <kbd>O</kbd> and scale on Y axis (<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>). while scaling, you can change the proportionnal editing radius with your mouse wheel. click to accept the scaling, right click to cancel.